# Why won't Ruby 1.9.2-head install using RVM?

Tags: ruby, rvm, ruby-1.9

I have been trying to install Ruby 1.9.2-head using RVM, but have been getting this error message:

```
echo executable host ruby is required
```

Is it compulsory to have system Ruby in order to install Ruby through RVM?

I have all the dependencies given in `rvm notes`, but I do not have any system Ruby installed. The error log shows:

```
[2011-05-02 07:42:19] make 
gcc -O3 -ggdb -Wextra -Wno-unused-parameter -Wno-parentheses -Wpointer-arith -Wwrite-strings -Wno-missing-field-initializers -Wno-long-long  -fPIC -I. -I.ext/include/i686-linux -I./include -I. -DRUBY_EXPORT   -o main.o -c main.c
gcc -O3 -ggdb -Wextra -Wno-unused-parameter -Wno-parentheses -Wpointer-arith -Wwrite-strings -Wno-missing-field-initializers -Wno-long-long  -fPIC -I. -I.ext/include/i686-linux -I./include -I. -DRUBY_EXPORT   -o dln.o -c dln.c
gcc -O3 -ggdb -Wextra -Wno-unused-parameter -Wno-parentheses -Wpointer-arith -Wwrite-strings -Wno-missing-field-initializers -Wno-long-long  -fPIC -I. -I.ext/include/i686-linux -I./include -I. -DRUBY_EXPORT   -o dmydln.o -c dmydln.c
gcc -O3 -ggdb -Wextra -Wno-unused-parameter -Wno-parentheses -Wpointer-arith -Wwrite-strings -Wno-missing-field-initializers -Wno-long-long  -fPIC -I. -I.ext/include/i686-linux -I./include -I. -DRUBY_EXPORT   -o dmyencoding.o -c dmyencoding.c
gcc -O3 -ggdb -Wextra -Wno-unused-parameter -Wno-parentheses -Wpointer-arith -Wwrite-strings -Wno-missing-field-initializers -Wno-long-long  -fPIC -I. -I.ext/include/i686-linux -I./include -I. -DRUBY_EXPORT   -o version.o -c version.c
gcc -O3 -ggdb -Wextra -Wno-unused-parameter -Wno-parentheses -Wpointer-arith -Wwrite-strings -Wno-missing-field-initializers -Wno-long-long  -fPIC -I. -I.ext/include/i686-linux -I./include -I. -DRUBY_EXPORT   -o dmyversion.o -c dmyversion.c
echo executable host ruby is required.  use --with-baseruby option.; false -I. ./tool/compile_prelude.rb ./prelude.rb miniprelude.c
executable host ruby is required. use --with-baseruby option.
make: *** [miniprelude.c] Error 1
```

Comment: It looks like you're on Linux. Ruby isn't installed by default on Linux, so it shouldn't be a prerequisite.

Comment: I confirmed that Ruby isn't a prerequisite by creating a new Linux Mint guest in VirtualBox, and installed RVM. It created the `~/.rvm` directory correctly.

Answer (score 6):

rvm notes also says

> To install Ruby 1.9.2 you need to have Ruby 1.8.7 installed and set.

So, install Ruby 1.8.7, load it to the environment and install ruby 1.9.2

```
rvm install ruby-1.8.7-head
rvm use ruby-1.8.7-head
rvm install ruby-1.9.2-head
```

This solution has been tested.

Answer (score 1):

You don't have to have a system Ruby, so long as you've installed another Ruby (probably Ruby MRI 1.8) through RVM.

Thankfully, Ruby 1.8 doesn't require you have Ruby installed, so you don't have a bootstrapping problem.